# Convert Oracle interval to Hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql select that transforms two datetime column difference into an interval:

`select column_1 - column_2 from my_table`

, which returns
`+04 02:21:28.000000`

I am using the `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (column_1 - column_2))` to get the hours, but it returns only the hour part, and not the 4 days as 96 hours.

I know I can extract the day portion and multiply by 24, but thats not what I am looking for (column_1 and column_2 are huge expressions, and I don't want to duplicate the statements).

I am on Oracle 12

Comment: re. huge expressions and not duplicating them ... you know you can put your query into a subquery and then do the calculation in the outer query? E.g. `select extract (day from (col1 - col2) *24 + extract(hour from (col1 - col2) from (select <some expression> col1, <some other expression> col2, ... from ....)`, or `with my_query as (select <some expression> col1, <some other expression> col2, ... from ...) select extract (day from (col1 - col2) *24 + extract(hour from (col1 - col2)`. (I'm not saying that adding days * 24 plus hours is the right thing to do, just giving an example of subquery.

Comment: @Boneist yes I knot that, but its not actually an option, as I have some limitations on what I can do. But thanks!

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a "datetime" data type.  It has dates that have a time component and it has timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your values are `TIMESTAMP` data types and not `DATE`. If you are not worried about fractional seconds then `CAST` them to a `DATE` and subtract:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR( ( CAST( column_1 AS DATE ) - CAST( column_2 AS DATE ) ) * 24 )
         AS hours_difference
FROM   my_table
```

Or, you can use a nested sub-query:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM difference ) * 24
       + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM difference )
       AS hours_difference
FROM   (
  SELECT column_1 - column_2 AS difference
  FROM   my_table
)
```

Or a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE):

```sql
WITH your_query( difference ) AS (
  SELECT column_1 - column_2 AS difference
  FROM   my_table
)
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM difference ) * 24
       + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM difference )
       AS hours_difference
FROM   your_query;
```

Which, or the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( column_1, column_2 ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-01-05 02:21:28', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

All the queries output:

> ```
> | HOURS_DIFFERENCE |
> | ---------------: |
> |               98 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f69ef48594c0a84f48128d19845d57da)*

Answer (score 1):

One method is to multiply by 24 and transform to an integer:

```
select floor( (column_1 - column_2) * 24 )
```

If you want decimal hours (i.e. fractions as well), just use:

```
select (column_1 - column_2) * 24
```

Comment: If I try that, it converts it to interval again (I just tried)